# Hide Inline Style in Chrome Dev Tools Elements

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to hide inline style tags

`style="position:fixed;top:0;"`

on HTML tags in Chrome Dev Tools Elements pane?

I'm using a custom JS framework that uses inline styles for styling components and this makes HTML debugging harder. `element.style{}` under Styles pane shows the style anyway so having it in the source is only a distraction, especially since some of these styles get massive.

Comment: No. Curious as to what framework you're using though, so I could make sure to steer clear of it.

Comment: Well... React uses inline styling for components as well so it's nothing that is not used commonly. It's an internal use, private, framework :-), you will never have to use it :-)

Comment: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: Getting more and more important